# Asp. Net: Testing Concurrency

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, concurrency

We have a website where companies have to upload zip files, and after the file is uploaded, the application check some things on the database, and then make some inserts.

The problem is that given the highen concurrency, the website is working really bad, and after speaking with the infraestructure team, we decided to re-design and re-develop the asp .net web application.

So, we are developing the application, and for avoiding the concurrency problem we had, i would like to know how can i test concurrency (telling a lot of people to upload files to the website is not an option) and monitor...

This is the first time i am doing something like this, so, i will appreciate ideas, articles, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The short simple and straightforward answer is [Jmeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) or e.g. [NeoLoad](http://answers.neotys.com/questions/838511-neoload-scripting). You may also consider Visual Studio [web tests](http://pabdulin.blogspot.be/2013/09/how-to-post-upload-file-in-visual.html) as an option if you have the Ultimate edition.

However I personally would just start with coding this in C# and paralleling the execution. Don't know your background, but since there's [C#] tag in question...

```
    private volatile int threads;

    [TestMethod]
    private void Main()
    {
        const int threadCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            ++threads;
            new Thread(LoadFile).Start();
        }
        while (threads > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void LoadFile()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //todo: do POST call
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        --threads;
    }
```

Take this as a **starting point**, this is definitely not something finished/ready for production. Logging, timing accumulation, threads count, replacing volatile int with `EventWaitHandle`s...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

The issue you're facing is indicating a much larger issue at hand... You could attempt to tackle it using Unit tests and optimizing things, but that's just sweeping the issue under the carpet...

You need a new approach from an architectural perspective, begin integrating a more service-oriented architecture. With the information you've provided, it's apparent that you have one web application attempting to take on too many responsibilities. You need to start splitting up responsibilities to different services and spread the load.

---

## The solution

You don't have to instantly process everything on the main web application, and attempting to do so will always bite back.

You can't control how many users will upload a document at any given moment, but you can manage the processing side of things which is where your issue is occurring.

Whenever a user uploads a file, store it, and add it to a queue to be processed by a different service, so from the web application you would add the document that's been uploaded to a queue, then a separate service that is running independently can go and process this item at the rate that you specify